# Thomas Precession on Neutron Stars

Tags: special-relativity, orbital-motion, neutron-stars, pulsars, spin-orbit

We know that Thomas Precession is a relativistic correction that is applied to a particle spin that adds an angular velocity to the spin of the particle that moves along a curvilinear orbit linked to the angular velocity. We have the equation

\begin{equation}
\vec{\omega}_T=\dfrac{\gamma^2}{\gamma+1}\dfrac{\vec{a} \times\vec{v}}{c^2}
\end{equation}

This correction is very significative in a semi-classical model of hydrogen atom and predicts correctly the anomalous Zeeman effect and Spin-orbit interaction. As reported on Jackson.
This formula can also be applied to macroscopic objects or planetary physical systems such as the Earth around the Sun or in a binary system of neutron stars.
In "The Theory of Special Relativity", Springer 2016 by Costas Christodoulides is reported the formula (in the case of $v\ll c$) where $\gamma^2/(\gamma+1)\approx 1/2$, for the period  $T_T=2\pi/\omega_T$

\begin{equation}\label{planet}
    T_T=\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\dfrac{c^3}{\mathcal{G}M}\right)^{2/3}T^{5/3}
\end{equation}

Where $T$ is the period of revolution. For a binary system, $M$ is reduced mass of the system and $\mathcal{G}$ is the gravitational force constant.
It is also reported that, in these cases, Thomas Precession does not appear, or better: in the case of binary star SDSS J0926+3624, which has the smallest known today orbital period of $28$ minutes, it is $T_T=1.7\times10^5$ years.
It does not play any role at all in planetary or stellar systems and is not observable, at least at present.
So my question: in the case of binary star system at the final stage of their lives where they can reach a velocity $v\approx 0.2c$ and if we consider them close enough such that relativistic laws become important. Has Thomas Precession some effect (maybe on the gravitational waves spectra) or it is still not observable at all? I am trying to consider the case where the period $T_T$ is enough small such that there exist some effects and if these scenarios really exist.